# Computing the predicted value from a panel data model with the plm R package

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am estimating the following panel data twoways fixed effect model:

```
y = alfa*y.lag + beta1*z + beta2*z^2 + theta*id + gamma*t     (1)
```

where `id` is the individual effect, `t` is the time effect. I am using the {plm} package in r, therefore the code goes like this

```
require(plm)
fe.full <- plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + z +z2, data = mdt, model= "within", effect="twoways")
```

Now I need to "extract" the predicted value for y. I know it can be done by doing `predict(fe.full)`, however I need to do that by hand for comparing it with other models specifications. Summing `alfa*y.lag + beta1*z + beta2*z^2` is not enough since I have to consider the coefficients for `id` and `t`. I know that the former can be obtained as `fixef(fe.full)`. However I dont know how to extract the value for the time effect. In Stata coefficients for time are displayed in the summary of the model. In R I was not able to manage that. I also tried to sum the coefficients for time taken from Stata to the value of `X*coeff + fixef(fe.full)` obtained in R, but still the output is not equal to the value given by `predict(fe.full)`. So I am doing something wrong, I guess.

Therefore the question is : how can I compute manually the sum of the right hand side of equation (1) starting from a `plm` object ?

Comment: You get the time effects with `fixef(your_model, effect = "time")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I finally managed it out, applying the suggestions by the authors of the plm package here http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/fitted-from-plm-td3003924.html

So what I did is just to apply

```
fitted <- as.numeric(fe.full$model[[1]] - fe.full$residuals)
```

where I need the as.numeric function since I need to use it as a vector to plug in for further manipulations. I also want to point out that if your model has a lagged dependent variable on the right hand side, the solution above with as.numeric provides a vector already NET of the missing values because of the lag. For me this is exactly what I needed to.

Cheers

Comment: for doing that "by hand" (as someone requested), see here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166531/hand-computation-for-plm-package-in-r-for-predicted-values/181450#181450

Comment: does not answer how to deal with time effect